# Questions on dihedral group and orthogonal group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am learning dihedral groups in my abstract algebra course. My teacher leaves us the following exercise. I can work out the first three parts only and I cannot even understand the question in part 5. Please feel free to offer help.

Question:

> Let $O(2, \mathbb{R}) = \{ A \in GL(2, \mathbb{R}) : A A^t = I \}$,
>   i.e. the orthogonal group. $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$ is the set containing
>   all invertible $2 \times 2$ matrices with real entries.
>
> 1. Prove that $O(2, \mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL(2, \mathbb{R})$.
> 2. Consider $D_n$, the dihedral group. Prove that $D_n \subset O(2, \mathbb{R})$.
> 3. Prove that $SO(2, \mathbb{R})$, the set of all $A \in O(2, \mathbb{R})$ such that $det(A) = 1$, is a subgroup of $O(2,
>     \mathbb{R})$.
> 4. Show that every element in $O(2, \mathbb{R})$ is of the form either $ \left(\begin{array}{ccc}cos \theta & sin \theta  \\-sin
>     \theta & cos \theta  \end{array} \right) $ or $
>     \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & 1  \\1 & 0  \end{array} \right) $$
>     \left(\begin{array}{ccc}cos \theta & sin \theta  \\-sin \theta & cos
>     \theta  \end{array} \right) $ for some $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.
> 5. Let $n \geq3$ be an integer. Consider the regular $n$-gon $\Gamma_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$ whose vertices are the $n$
>      points $(cos\frac{2\pi k}{n}, sin\frac{2 \pi k}{n})$. Prove that $D_n
>     = \{ A \in O(2, \mathbb{R}): A(\Gamma_n)=\Gamma_n\}$.

The first three parts are trivial. I have successfully shown all of them. But what about question 4 and 5? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Part 5 should be understood in the context of part 2, where it is claimed that the dihedral group "occurs" as a subgroup of $O(2,\mathbb{R})$.  With the help of parts 3,4 you are expected to show a specific way of "representing" the dihedral group within the orthogonal group.

Comment: How would one show part $2$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part four, write down
$$
\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ d & d \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and consider two cases:

- $a = 0$
- $a \ne 0$

The first will lead you to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \pm 1 \\ \pm 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
The second will lead you to $c = -b$, and $a^2 + c^2 = 1$. Set $\theta = atan2(c, a)$, and observe that for this $\theta$, $a = q\cos \theta, c = q\sin \theta$ ... and then that $q = \pm 1$. That pretty much handles part 4.

Once you've done that, part 5 should not be too bad. The subgroup $G$ of $O(2, R)$ specified certainly contains rotation by $h = 2\pi k / n$, and hence all its powers. Since its $n$th power is the identity, you've got a $Z/nZ$ in $G$. It also contains a flip about a horizontal axis. That's the order-2 element of $D_n$. Now all you have to do is set of a mapping and prove it's an isomorphism.

Post-comment edit: 
I'm not sure how you've defined $D_n$. I think of it as a group with two generators $a$ and $b$, and relations $a^n = b^2 = e$ and $bab = a^{-1}$. Others say "it's the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon." I'm sure there are other definitions. If you go with my definition, you need to find a map from $D_n$ to the subgroup $G$, and since $a$ and $b$ are generators, you just need to show where to send those. You send $a$ to 
$$
f(a) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos u & -\sin u \\ \sin u & \cos u \end{bmatrix} 
$$
where $u = 2\pi /n$. You then compute $f(a^k) = f(a)^k$, for $k = 1, 2, \ldots$ and show none of these is the identity until  $f(a^n) = I_2$.

Then you send $b$ to an element of order $2$ in $G$ ... like reflection through the $x$ axis, i.e. 
$$
f(b) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$

Now confirm that $f(b)^2 = I_2$, thus checking that the second "relation" holds.

Finally, you need to check that $f(bab) = f(a)^{-1}$, which is just a bunch of matrix multiplication.

Once you've done this, you know that $f$ is a homomorphism, it's kernel is $\{e\}$, and the only question is "is it surjective?". To prove surjectivity, suppose that $M$ is a matrix in $O(n)$ that preserves $\Gamma_n$. Call the points of $\Gamma_n$ $v_0, \ldots, v_n$, where $v_k$ corresponds to $2\pi k/n$.

Then $M v_0 = v_k$ for some $k$. Let $M_k$ be "rotation through angle $2\pi k/n$", i.e., $f(a^k)$. Then we have 
$$
M_k^{-1} M v_0 = v_0
$$
which is a matrix in $O(2)$ that holds fixed the horizontal axis. That makes it have to be 
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & \pm 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
If it's the identity, then $M = M_k = f(a^{k}$, so $M$ is in the image of $f$.

If it's the other matrix, which happens to be $f(b)$, then we have
$$
f(a^{-k}) M = f(b) \\
M = f(b) f(a^{k})
$$
and once again $M$ is in the image of $M$. So $f$ is surjective, injective, and a homomorphism. Thus it's an isomorphism onto a subgroup of $O(2)$.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I think I understand question 4 now. For question 5, I find that the solution includes $Z/nZ$, is it the quotient group? Is there a way to prove it in stead of using the concept of quotient group?

Comment: Further details added.

Comment: +1 for "I'm not sure how you've define $D_n$".  There are two competing notations, which you can sort out from aspects of the problem statement, but some definition must already have been in play for part 2.

Answer (score 2):

**Part 4** Note that translating the condition $AA^T = I$ into statements about the rows and columns of $A$ simply says that $A$ is orthonormal iff its columns form and orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ (with respect to the usual inner product). Since the first column of $A$ has unit length, we can write it as $$(\cos \theta, -\sin \theta).$$ The second column must be orthogonal to this and have unit length, and so must be able to write it as
$$\pm (\sin \theta, \cos \theta)$$
for some choice of $\pm$. The choice $+$ leads to the first form, and the choice $-$ leads (after an appropriate change of parameter) to the second.

**Part 5** This is somewhat involved, and partly depends on what definition you're using for $D_n$ in the first place. But even without knowing that we can get starting by identifying explicitly the subgroup of $O(n)$ that maps $\Gamma_n$ to itself: Any element $A \in O(n)$ such that $A(\Gamma_n) = \Gamma_n$ must in particular send the point $(1, 0)$ to one of the other vertices of $\Gamma_n$, say, to $\left(\cos \frac{2\pi k}{n}, \sin \frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)$, and by definition, this is the first column of $A$. By the above characterization, this determines the second element up to sign. There are $n$ possibilities for $k$, and each leads to two possibilities for $\pm$, giving a total of $2n$ matrices, and checking directly shows that all of these do indeed map $\Gamma_n$ to $\Gamma_n$.